# How can I print the parameters of a function before evaluation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Using a function like `show` will evaluate any expression given to it before printing. If I call `show (12+4)` the output will be `16`. How can I write a function that prints the output directly, ie when called with `12+4` will return `12+4` or `(12+4)`

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible. Functions receive *values* as arguments, not expressions. 16 is a value. 12+4 is an expression, a way of computing 16. If you want to know how 16 was computed, you will have to instrument `+`, not the function called with the result of `+`.

Comment: Haskell uses lazy evaluation. The parameter should be received as an expression and not evaluated until used.

Comment: @user7685672 That's an implementation detail. Conceptually, the function doesn't have any access to the thunk, only what the thunk represents.

Comment: It's not just an implementation detail, it's also inaccurate. Yes, there is non-strict evaluation. But you can't conclude from that that functions have access to expressions representing their arguments, only that the function gets something which may be a thunk or may be a fully-computed value. Importantly, a thunk doesn't imply any kind of textual or syntactic representation.

Comment: `putStrLn "(12+4)"`

Comment: Sadly, it seems even the GHCi debugger can't do this. It can tell you which integers are evaluated and which are not, but it seems it cannot print the actual expression waiting to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Pure functions can not print anything. To print something a function must return a value in the IO monad.

*However*, I guess that you want to print the arguments for debugging purposes, only. For this specific task, there's an utility function called `Debug.Trace.trace` which does just that.

A typical usage is as follows:

```
import Debug.Trace

fib :: Int -> Int
fib n | trace ("fib input:" ++ show n) False = undefined
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

The first branch "tricks" GHC to evaluate `trace ("fib input:" ++ show n) False`, which returns `False` after printing some debug output. Because the guard is false, the `= undefined` part will be ignored.

Do not use this feature for anything else than debugging.

You might also want to take a look to the [GHCi debugger](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) for more advanced debugging techniques.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but if I call that function with (12+4), show n will still evaluate the parameter. I'm looking to print out 12+4 literally to the terminal

Comment: @user7685672 I see. The problem is that 12+4 gets evaluates to 16, and there's no way to distinguish between those integers.